# HTML issue compatibility view lot of data IE Struts2

Tags: html, internet-explorer, jsp, struts2, compatibility

I have a web page using JSP and Struts2.

On this page I have a struts Iterator with quite a lot data (around 200).
I write for each data I have one tag `tr`.

My problem is under this list, I have another property which doesn't appear when I load the page but If I change the style of one tag on the page with the developer tool of IE, It automatically appears.

The property is in the source code and just doesn't appear. But it work well without the compatibility view.

If someone knows this issue and how solve it (without write `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >` in my page).

Comment: Post the code that has the problems.

Comment: Can you show us your jsp page?

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't see your answer; this is the file.jsp